# How can I create software groups in RHN Satellite?

Tags: redhat, satellite, rhn, spacewalk

I would like to be able to create software groups, so I can install a group of packages with yum groupinstall, e.g.

```
yum groupinstall oracle-packages
```

Does RHN Satellite support software groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to use package groups with Satellite - at least I've never found one - but you can get the same effect by crating a package that has no payload but does have dependencies. Simply list all the packages you wish to install via the proposed `yum groupinstall` command in the `Requires:` section and it will pull in all those packages for you.